# Getting the value of a select option

Tags: forms

I would like to validate the company name chosen in a form in a "select" form field.

When I try `$form_values['submitted_tree']['company_1'];` it shows me the key instead of the string value.

I tried the following code, but it still prints '1' (the key) instead of the value associated with the key.

```
    $_page_num = $form_state['values']['details']['page_num'];
    $key1 = $form_state['values']['submitted_tree']['company_1'];
    $value1 = $form['submitted_tree']['company_1']['#options'][$key1];
    $key2 = $form_state['values']['submitted_tree']['company_2'];
    $value2 = $form['submitted_tree']['company_2']['#options'][$key2];

    if (($_page_num == 2) && ($value1 == $value2)) {
      drupal_set_message(print_r($form['submitted_tree']['company_2']['#options'][$key2]));
    }
```

Could anyone help me to retrieve the actual text value displayed in select option chosen? I have tried `$form_state` as well, but it returns the same result.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the key to get the value by referencing the options array in the original form element:

```
$key = $form_state['values']['submitted_tree']['company_1'];
$value = $form['submitted_tree']['company_1']['#options'][$key];
```

Comment: Hi Clive,
I tried this, but its still showing me '1'
I have edited the qn, with the code I used. Kindly let me know if its fine.

Comment: What reported by Clive is the only way to get that value. If you are not getting a different string, probably the form field just used "1" as option value, and not `array("1" => "String to show")`.

Comment: note that the "submitted tree" is not a drupal standard, but reflects the structure of the op's form. For a flat form simply delete the `['submitted_tree']` bit and, of course, change `['company_1']` to your own element id.