# Redirect Page on Change of Exposed Filter

Tags: views, 8, hooks, ajax

We have an `All Articles` view that is added to the `http://www.example.com/articles` page that is supposed to display all pages where content type is `Article`. The content type has a taxonomy term, `Category`, which has several filter values such as `IoT`, `Security`, and `Cloud`. On the view, the `field_category` is exposed for visitors to change the value and it will automatically update the results (`Use Ajax = true`).

**Goal:**

- On change of the exposed filter to `Cloud`, we would like to redirect the user to another page (`http://www.example.com/some-page`).

**Question:**

- **How would we redirect a user to the other page when the exposed filter is set to `Cloud`?**

View Settings:

Format

- Format: Unformatted List | setting (`default settings`)
- Show: Content | Listing (`custom view mode`)

Filter Criteria

- content: published (= yes)
- content: content type (= Article)
- content: category (exposed)

Advanced

- Use Ajax: `Yes`
- Query Option: `Distinct = true`

Here is what we tried, but it does not redirect with no errors.

**mymodule.module**

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'view_exposed_form' && $form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-articles-page-1') {

   if($form['field_category_target_id'] == '123') {
     $form['field_category_target_id']['#ajax] = [
       'callback' => 'cloud_ajax_callback',
       'wrapper' => 'category_cloud',
     ],
   }
  }
}

function cloud_ajax_callback($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $response = new AjaxResponse();
  $cloud_cmd = $new RedirectCommand('http://www.example.com/some-page');
  return $response->addCommand($cloud_cmd);
}
```

Comment: Not an expert, but have gone down this path a bit. If I understand correctly, the issue is that $form_state doesn't have an" event listener" for the `'#options'` array state change in the context you need. Even `$form_state->setRebuild(TRUE);` needs an interaction from some `$form` element (e.g. submit). This task could easily be achieved with javascript/jQuery.

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/277980/get-an-un-submitted-active-form-field-value-in-form-state. And the most recent result I could find that I think relates to this question: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/21355/getting-the-value-of-a-select-option (n/a here).

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change `#action` in the form.

so

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'view_exposed_form' && $form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-articles-page-1') {
       $form["#action"] = "THE_PATH_YOU_WANT_TO_REDIRECT";
  }
}
```